# get DDNS & openVPN to work in subnetwork

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, subnet

I am currently using an Asus RT-AC51U to create a subnetwork in my apartment building's shared network.

Now I'd love to be able to control my smart-home environment from outside my network via OpenVPN.

However, the router's software notes me to the following when trying to enable DDNS:

```
The wireless router currently uses a private WAN IP address.
This router may be in the multiple-NAT environment and DDNS service cannot work in this environment.
```

Is it possible to still install OpenVPN in this network structure (especially without access to the shared-network's router)? Can anyone hint me on how to possibly approach this / what to look out for?

Comment: Do you have a server at home? If yes, you need something like VPN Azure (http://vpnazure.net/en/)

Comment: I do have a router which is supposed to be able to host a vpn.